# Show that the notation of ordered pair as $(x,y) :=\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ obeys the property that $(x,y) = (x', y')$ iff $x=x'$ and $y=y'$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Suppose we deﬁne the ordered pair $(x,y)$ for any objects $x$ and $y$ by the formula $(x,y) := \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$. Thus for instance $(1,2)$ is the set $\{\{1\},\{1,2\}\}$, $(2 ,1)$ is the set $\{\{2\},\{2,1\}\}$, and $(1,1)$ is the set $\{\{1\}\}$. Show that such a deﬁnition indeed obeys the property that $(x,y) = (x', y')$ iff $x=x'$ and $y=y'$, and also whenever $X$ and $Y$ are sets, the Cartesian product $X × Y$ is also a set.

If $(x,y) = (x', y')$ then by the formula $\{\{x\},\{x,y\}\} = \{\{x'\},\{x',y'\}\}$.

The two sets are equal iff every element of the first set belongs to the second set and vice versa.

So, ($\{x\} \in \{\{x'\},\{x',y'\}\}$ and $\{x,y\} \in \{\{x'\},\{x',y'\}\}$) and 
($\{x'\} \in \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$ and $\{x',y'\} \in \{\{x\},\{x,y\}\}$).

Show that $\{x\} = \{x'\}$ and $\{x,y\} = \{x',y'\}$.

How to proceed? Should I try all the possible combinations of where $x$ can be and where $y$ can be?

Comment: What is the definition of two sets being equal? It's pretty simple once you write that down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, try with cases : if $\{x\}=\{x'\}$ or $\{x\}=\{x',y'\}$ and when $\{x,y\}=\{x'\}$ or is $\{x,y\}=\{x',y'\}$.